# Mysql carrying out the rate according to the range given

Tags: mysql, case

I have a below table in `mysql`.

```
CREATE TABLE `mdc_tariff_slabs` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
`type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`slab_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Slab',
`slab_start` int(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Start of the slab',
`slab_end` int(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'End of the slab',
`rate` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Rate of slab',
`t_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tariff ID, Foriegn Key',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `T_ID` (`t_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `T_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`t_id`) REFERENCES `mdc_tariff` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `mdc_tariff_slabs` */

insert  into `mdc_tariff_slabs`(`id`,`type`,`slab_name`,`slab_start`,`slab_end`,`rate`,`t_id`) values (1,NULL,'S-1',1,100,'10',1),(2,NULL,'S-2',101,150,'12',1),(3,NULL,'S-3',151,NULL,'14',1),(4,NULL,'S-1',1,50,'5',2),(5,NULL,'S-2',51,100,'7',2),(6,NULL,'S-3',101,NULL,'8',2),(52,'WAPDA','S-1',1,100,'12',12),(53,'WAPDA','S-2',101,150,'14',12),(54,'WAPDA','S-3',151,NULL,'16',12),(58,'Generator','S-1',1,100,'17',12),(59,'Generator','S-2',101,150,'20',12),(60,'Generator','S-3',151,NULL,'22',12);
```

The same is in my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fb749)

I have slabs range. Within that range of a particular `type` I want to check the `rate`. Assuming the value to be checked is `40` and the `type` is `Generator`. So if the value is in the slab range `1-100` the rate would be `17` and vice versa.

**Expected Output**

```
 type     |value|rate|
======================
 Generator| 40  |17  |
....
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like slabs can overlap, so you should go for the `MAX` of slab value to ensure you're handling bad data. This is tricky, because you have `rate` defined as a varchar. That's why I'm casting it to an int value before summing it. You may still have issues with this. I suggest instead going with an int value for that column.

It also looks like the `slab_end` can be `NULL`, representing no end, so a simple `BETWEEN` condition won't work for your case. I handled it with an `OR` condition.

Here's how I would do it:

```
SET @value = 40;
SET @type = 'Generator';

SELECT @type AS type,
    @value AS value,
    MAX(CAST(rate AS UNSIGNED)) AS rate
FROM mdc_tariff_slabs
WHERE type = @type
    AND @value >= slab_start
    AND (@value <= slab_end OR slab_end IS NULL);
```

Comment: no I don't want to sum it. I just want to get the rate within the range. If `type=Generator` and if the value is between `1-100` the rate would be `17`, if the value is between `101-150` the rate is `20` and if it's above `150` the rate will be `22` and so on

Comment: @FaisalQayyum got it - edited my response to address that